# Is there a login / display manager in Linux with a config GUI for setting wallpaper (NOT editing config files by CLI)?

Tags: gui, display-manager, login-manager

I have looked and not found one. I'm surprised, as something as trivial as this should be configurable via a GUI. Even SDDM for KDE doesn't offer this and KDE is normally super configurable via GUI.
This is NOT about doing this by command line and editing config files, that is possible.

Comment: I'm amazed that I got -2 for this, a legitimate question. A valid answer could be: There is no such thing and the question would be resolved. Instead I get minus points for a question I (supposedly) should have never asked in the first place??? :-(

Comment: This might be a valid question, indeed. Downvotes are awarded when a member thinks you did not try hard enough to find a solution or are trying to troll. TBH, last time I used a config file to set a wallpaper in Linux must have been 2002, maybe, well I probably did, always on purpose, though ... However, I do not use KDE AND there actually was a bug in SDDM that prevented you from setting a background wallpaper.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=370521

This was resolved in version 5.9.1

It only affected some themes, from what I understand. which version do you have ?

Comment: There are a ton of bugs open about this, looks like SDDM does not like some picture formats. I'm using KDE (Plasma) 5.8.6 on Debian Stretch. This is a workable solution, I accepted the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: SDDM settings]
You absolutely can change the SDDM background through the GUI, it's right there in System Settings.